# Get Duplicate data from the Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to fetch duplicate data from the database but the problem is:
i have userids in an array like :

```
1235, 1235, 5468, 84321, 1235
```

i used implode and to make that array in string in implement into the database like:

```
"select * from tbl_name where userid in ('" . $implode_arr . "') limit 0, 10";
```

which is give me the result like `1235, 5468, 84321` but i want all the data, solution for this is simply run the query in the `FOR LOOP` or else

but i want same because i add the pagination within the query.

I don't want any code because its already working but the problem is to add pagination Please help to resolve the problem :(

Comment: Are you concerned about creating pagination out of it or do you want to correct anything in the given code?

Comment: @OMTheEternity thanks for quick reply i just want all the result with duplicate through an array

Comment: Is it like you want to run a single query on two different database at the same time to find the duplicates?

Comment: @OMTheEternity yes, if possible

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046416/how-to-use-sql-connection-in-php-to-execute-a-query-on-two-databases

Comment: @OMTheEternity thanks a lot, to continue with me. i did with some other logic, but your given link also important. i will work on it soon, i add it on my Favorite. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to join in the user data into this query. You can do that using a LEFT JOIN like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_name
LEFT JOIN database_name.user ON database_name.user.id = tbl_name.userid
WHERE userid IN (...)
LIMIT 0, 10
```

This is assuming your users are stored in the `user` table in the `database_name` database, and that the user table has an `id` field which matches up to the `tbl_name` field `userid`. If your fields or table names are different, just change them in this query. In PHP that would be:

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl_name LEFT JOIN database_name.user ON database_name.user.id = tbl_name.userid WHERE userid IN ('" . $implode_arr . "') LIMIT 0, 10"
```

Note that to connect two databases, both must be accessible by your same connected user.

Comment: Thanks but the problem with this i have two different databases, this will work with the single database. But if it is possible to connect two database without any conflict on server then it will great.

Comment: @SamArulRaj you are right but i mentioned my another problem.

Comment: @jogesh_p, yes you can connect two databases. You just have to prefix the table name with the database name. I updated my answer to show this.

Comment: @jogesh_p, to do this, both databases have to be accessible by the same database user.

Comment: @BenLee is it work on the server? because i am working on the PHP 4.4.9, and before my query i add the connection like `require('connection_file.php');`, now like i have `db_one` and `db_two`, which connection i have used before the query `require('connetion_one_db_one')` or `require('connection_two_db_two')`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it would also work as expected**

```
     select * from tbl_name where FIND_IN_SET(user_id,'1235, 1235, 5468, 84321, 1235
') limit 1,10
```

[Check this to remove duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596790/mysql-query-return-duplicate-entries-with-in-and-find-int-set)